# Products of logarithms under the integral sign

Tags: indefinite-integrals

This question is a simplification of a previously asked question: [Polylogarithmic integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066489/polylogarithmic-integrals)

Consider the following type of function:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\prod_{i=1}^N \log(x-\beta_i)}{x-\alpha} dx
\end{equation}

For the simple case of $N=2$ we have the following integral,
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\log(x-B) \log(x-C)}{x-A} dx
\end{equation}
the result of which is already highly complicated. See for example the way the Risch algorithm in Wolfram Alpha tackles it: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Clog(x-B)%20*%20%5Clog(x-C)%20%2F%20(x-A)%20dx). The dream is to generalise this $N=2$ result, but I can't seem to find information, references or some other canonical answer for the result shown in Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica/[RUBI](https://rulebasedintegration.org). Needless to say, my own efforts to derive the result have failed identically.

Sadly, for the case for $N=3$ logarithms under the integral, Wolfram Alpha and related methods do not even have *any* answer ready. From what I can see, Wolfram uses a lookup table to determine what the resulting integrand will look like for $N=2$, and there is no $N=3$ entry in the table.

The most verbose "step-by-step" derivation I have found was through RUBI, where RUBI rule 2485 appears to be invoked. This lead me to page 36 [in this pdf](https://rulebasedintegration.org/PdfRuleFiles/3%20Logarithms/3.3%20u%20(a+b%20log(c%20(d+e%20x)%5En))%5Ep.pdf), which appears to hint at some obscure sequence of integration by parts and substitutions, but I have found nothing that results in the expressions shown in that PDF.

Since I would like to somehow find a structure for higher $N$ of the above more general integral: does anyone have a reference for how to derive the ($N=2$) result shown in Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica? Or perhaps give a derivation of the result themselves? I'm aware I can take the derivative of the Wolfram Alpha result, but this will not give me new information on how to solve when $N=3$, so solutions going from the original integral to the result, as if there is no prior knowledge of the result, are the only ones I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do the first two steps of the attached PDF:

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\log(a+bx)\log(c+dx)}{x} dx &=\log(a+bx)\log(c+dx)\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - b\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log(c+dx)}{a+bx} - d\int \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log(a+bx)}{c+dx} \\
&=\log(a+bx)\log(c+dx)\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - b\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \left[\log(c+dx) - \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{a+bx} -\cdots\\
&\phantom=\cdots- b\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]}{a+bx}- d\int dx\frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \left[\log(a+bx) + \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{c+dx} + \cdots \\
&\phantom= \cdots+ d \int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]}{c+dx} \\
&=\log(a+bx)\log(c+dx)\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - b\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \left[\log(c+dx) - \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{a+bx} -\cdots\\
&\phantom=\cdots- d\left[\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - \log\left[-\frac{dx}{c}\right]\right]\int dx\frac{\log(a+bx) + \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]}{c+dx} - \cdots \\
&\phantom= \cdots -d\int dx\frac{\log\left[-\frac{dx}c\right]\left[\log(a+bx) + \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{c+dx} - \int dx \log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\left[\frac{ b(c+dx)-d(a+bx)}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}\right]\\
&=\log(a+bx)\log(c+dx)\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - b\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \left[\log(c+dx) - \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{a+bx} -\cdots\\
&\phantom=\cdots- d\left[\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] - \log\left[-\frac{dx}{c}\right]\right]\int dx\frac{\log(a+bx) + \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]}{c+dx} - \cdots \\
&\phantom= \cdots -d\int dx\frac{\log\left[-\frac{dx}c\right]\left[\log(a+bx) + \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]\right]}{c+dx} - (bc-ad)\int dx \frac{\log\left[-\frac{bx}a\right] \log\left[\frac{a(c+dx)}{c(a+bx)}\right]}{(a+bx)(c+dx)}
\end{align*}

This reduces the integral to known integrals.

I have used the "add and subtract" method, and I have exchanged the constant inside the logarithm by twofold partial integration, back and forth. If anything is unclear leave a comment:)

Answer (score 4):

He we derive the result for $N=2$. We assume that $A \in {\mathbb R}$, $B \in {\mathbb R}$ and $C \in {\mathbb R}$. 
Then we also take $x_1 \in {\mathbb R}$ and $x_2 \in {\mathbb R}$ such that $max(A,B,C) \le x_1 < x_2$.

We note an identity:
\begin{equation}
u v=\frac{1}{4} \left[ (u+v)^2 - (u-v)^2\right] \quad (i)
\end{equation}
and we also note the following anti-derivative:
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{\log[u]^n}{u+A} du = \sum\limits_{p=1}^{n+1} (-1)^p \binom{n}{p-1} (p-1)! Li_p(-\frac{u}{A}) \log[u]^{n-p+1} \quad (ii)
\end{equation}
Let us define:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak I}_A^{(B,C)}:=\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\log(x-B)\log(x-C)}{x-A} dx
\end{equation}
then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathfrak I}_A^{(B,C)}=\\
&&\frac{1}{4} \left( 
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{[\log[(x-B)(x-C)]]^2}{x-A} dx-
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{[\log[\frac{x-B}{x-C}]]^2}{x-A} dx
\right)=\\
&&\frac{1}{4} \left(
\int\limits_{x_1-B}^{x_2-B} \frac{\log[u]^2}{u+B-A} du + +
2 {\mathfrak I}_A^{(B,C)}+
\int\limits_{x_1-C}^{x_2-C} \frac{\log[u]^2}{u+C-A} du-
\int\limits_{\frac{x_1-B}{x_1-C}}^{\frac{x_2-B}{x_2-C}} \left( \frac{1}{1-u} + \frac{1}{u+\frac{A-B}{C-A}}\right) \log[u]^2 du
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
In the first line we took $(u,v):=(\log(x-B),\log(x-C))$ and we used the identity $(i)$ and in the second line we substituted for $u=(x-B)/(x-C)$ in the second integral and we expanded the numerator in the first integral into three terms and substituted accordingly. At this point it was essential to assume that $max(A,B,C)<x_1<x_2$ since otherwise the argument of the logarithm may jump by $\pm 2 \pi$.

Therefore we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathfrak I}_A^{(B,C)}= \frac{1}{2} \left(\right.\\
&&\left.
\left.
\sum\limits_{p=1}^3 (-1)^p \binom{2}{p-1} (p-1)! Li_p (\frac{x}{A-B}) \log[x]^{3-p} \right|_{x_1-B}^{x_2-B} +\right.\\
&&\left.
\left.
\sum\limits_{p=1}^3 (-1)^p \binom{2}{p-1} (p-1)! Li_p (\frac{x}{A-C}) \log[x]^{3-p} \right|_{x_1-C}^{x_2-C} +\right.\\
&&\left.
\left.
\sum\limits_{p=1}^3 (-1)^p \binom{2}{p-1} (p-1)! Li_p (x) \log[x]^{3-p} \right|_{\frac{x_1-B}{x_1-C}}^{\frac{x_2-B}{x_2-C}} -\right.\\
&&\left.
\left.
\sum\limits_{p=1}^3 (-1)^p \binom{2}{p-1} (p-1)! Li_p (x \frac{A-C}{A-B}) \log[x]^{3-p} \right|_{\frac{x_1-B}{x_1-C}}^{\frac{x_2-B}{x_2-C}}\right.\\
&&\left.
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where we used the anti-derivative $(ii)$.

```
In[3396]:= {x1, x2} = 
  Sort[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
{A, B, CC} = RandomReal[{-20, x1}, 3, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
Delta[f_, a_, b_] := f[b] - f[a]; n = 2;

 NIntegrate[(Log[(x - B)] Log[(x - CC)])/(x - A), {x, x1, x2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
1/2 (Delta[
    Sum[(-1)^p Binomial[n, p - 1] (p - 1)! PolyLog[
        p, #/(A - B)]  Log[#]^(n - p + 1), {p, 1, n + 1}] &, x1 - B, 
    x2 - B] + 
   Delta[Sum[(-1)^p Binomial[n, p - 1] (p - 1)! PolyLog[
        p, #/(A - CC)]  Log[#]^(n - p + 1), {p, 1, n + 1}] &, x1 - CC,
     x2 - CC] +
   Delta[Sum[(-1)^p Binomial[n, p - 1] (p - 1)! PolyLog[
        p, #]  Log[#]^(n - p + 1), {p, 1, n + 1}] &, (x1 - B)/(
    x1 - CC), (x2 - B)/(x2 - CC)] - 
   Delta[Sum[(-1)^p Binomial[n, p - 1] (p - 1)! PolyLog[
        p, # ((A - CC)/(A - B))]  Log[#]^(n - p + 1), {p, 1, 
       n + 1}] &, (x1 - B)/(x1 - CC), (x2 - B)/(x2 - CC)])

Out[3399]= 0.97636054602843021192

Out[3400]= 0.9763605460284302119212052702582348188593322097
```

Comment: What was the reason for down-voting this answer ?